# SVG: Is the "font-size" attribute allowed in "<g>" Elements?

Tags: svg, language-lawyer, font-size

The SVG 1.1 [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html) says that the `font-size` attribute is allowed in text content elements. The `<g>` element is **not** a text content element. Conclusively, the `<g font-size="45"/>` is illegal.

However, many examples in the standard show `<g>`-elements with the `font-size` attribute.

Is the attribute allowed in `<g>` elements or are the examples showing invalid code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

font-size is an [inherited CSS property](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#FontSizeProperty) so if you set it on a parent element, it applies to all that element's children.

It can have an indirect effect on non-text elements if they use em or ex units i.e. they are sized relative to the font-size. What the specification is trying (pretty poorly) to say is that setting a font-size on a rect element won't have any effect.

The specification for a [g element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#GElement) is explicit that font-size is a property it supports. Click on the presentation-attributes link in the g element section on that page and the text will expand to show font-size as a supported attribute.